# Hello World Error

Tags: applescript, macos

I'm learning AppleScript and my first program is a Hello World(of course!):

```
display dialog "Hello World"
```

But when I try to run this I got the error:

> The result of a numeric operation was too large.

- Why this?
- How I can solve it?

Comment: There has to be more to the story here. What are you creating and running the script in?

Comment: And that is the entirety of the script, or at least what is displayed in the window you are creating this in? Have you done anything else beforehand? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @Philip Yes, that's all and I've tried to reboot.

Comment: Have you tried any other code to see what the result might be? Not a display dialog but something a bit more complex? I've just never seen anything like what you've noted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [The Ultimate Beginner’s Guide To AppleScript – Mac.AppStorm](http://mac.appstorm.net/how-to/applescript/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-applescript/)

```
tell application "Finder"

    display dialog "Hello World"

end tell
```

Comment: The tell block shouldn't be necessary. I can run the code given by the  OP without error.